# How install pyaudio in python3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how install pyaudio in python3.9 ?
C:\Users\Baali>pip install PyAudio
cannot install pyaudio in python3.9
how i do ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) and download the corresponding wheel, thus for a 32 bit system go with `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl`and for a 64 bit system choose `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`.

Navigate via cmd.exe to your download path, i.e.

```
cd <download_path>
```

and respectively install:

```
pip install <name_of_the_wheel>
```

, whereas the name might be either for the 32 bit or 64 bit version.

Voilà, you have **PyAudio for Python 3.9 downloaded**!

Comment: @J.Doe No, it also works for Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and as shown above 3.9. Just check the link https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio and search for the version indicated by `cpxx`, whereas `xx` is the binary of the version.